# Is there any way in Redis to put keys without any common regx pattern in the same hash slots?

Tags: caching, redis, amazon-elasticache, redis-cluster

I have the following data model for which I want to use redis as cache.

Employee: With a unique Employee_Id.

Department: With a unique Department_Id.

An employee can be part of only one department, a department can have many employees. Now, the operations the system should support are something like this.

1. Given a Employee_Id, find the department it is a part of.
2. Given a Department_Id, find the list of all it's employees.
3. Merge to departments, in this case employees of any one department will move to other, depending on the least no.of db operations.

I'm using DynamoDB as the persistent storage with two tables representing Employee and Department. I'm performing merge operations using dynamodb transactions, to ensure ACID.

Now, I'm planning to use redis as a cache between service and db. For each employee_Id as key, I'll store the department it is part of. For each department_id as key, I'll store the the list of members in the department. Now, for merge usecase I'll have to update the values for a no.of employee -> department mapping. For this I want to use redis transactions or operations like MSET, MGET etc.

For transactions in redis, we need to ensure that all keys are in the same hash slots. However, in our case EmployeeId(Key) are randomly generated UUID, they will not have any common regx. pattern to use for hash-tags. But, the values that they point to, i.e. Depatment_id will be common for them.

Is there any way in Redis to put keys(employee_Id) without any common regx pattern  in same hash slots?

I'll put all such entries(for which I might want to perform transactions in future) in redis at the same time, hence I was thinking of appending a random string as hash-tag (between '{' and '}') to the keys but while getting value for the key, I'll not know the random the random string added, I need fetch values based on the original keys only.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but can't you use the Department_Id for that?
Meaning: `Employee_Id:{Department_Id}` this way all the employees from the same department will have the same slot_id as their department

Comment: @GuyKorland Do you mean adding Department_Id to the key? 

I want to be able to fetch Department_Id for a given Employee_Id. I can't to do this if Department_Id is added to key itself.